# spring boot micro-service giving: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

We have a microservice developed using Sprig Boot. This microservice will called an external Rest API. This is deployed on multiple servers. On one of the servers we are seeing the following error

```
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:669)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:413)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:137)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
        ....
        Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:351)
....
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
```

on the other servers the same service is running fine.

We tried traceroute on this server and other servers but the output on both are same. We restarted the service but same error.

Any pointers on what we can debug and find where the issue is?

Comment: `Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset` makes me think its a cert issue, verify you have valid certs on the one server its not working on.

Answer (score 0):

This thread can be closed as after the restart of that service, its working fine.